# How to listen to the Flutter in-app web browser?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I am using the flutter_web_browser package from Flutter to open a web browser inside the app. I want to navigate to another page when the browser window closes. The function `openWebPage` is of type Future, so I've tried using then() and whenComplete(), but neither of these functions are entered when I close the browser manually or the browser closes using deep links.

```
final url = "https://google.com";

    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text("Click ME"),
        onPressed: () async {
           await FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
            url: "$url",
            androidToolbarColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          ).whenComplete(() {
            print('OVER');
          });
        },
      ),
    );
```

How do I get the app to listen to when the browser closes and navigate to another screen accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going out of the app( which is pause on App lifecycles) you cannot listen to whats happening on the background or some other app. As a work around you can Listen to app life cycles and do the Navigation. [Flutter App Life Cycles](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html), [Flutter App Life Cycles Implementation](https://medium.com/pharos-production/flutter-app-lifecycle-4b0ab4a4211a).

Or else you can use the In-App web browser which consists of the functionality you needed.
[Flutter In app web browser](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

Hope this helps!